# Javascript replace doesn't work when it should

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var src = "http://blah.com/SOMETHING.jpg";
src.replace(/.*([A-Z])\.jpg$/g, "X");
```

at this point, shouldn't src be:

> http://blah.com/SOMETHINX.jpg

If I use match() with the same regular expression, it says it matched. Regex Coach also shows a match on the character "G".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
src = src.replace(/.*([A-Z])\.jpg$/g, "X");
```

String#replace isn't a mutator method; it returns a new string with the modification.

EDIT: Separately, I don't think that regexp is exactly what you want. It says "any number of any character" followed by a captured group of one character A-Z followed by ".jpg" at the end of the string.  `src` becomes simply "X".

Answer (score 1):

The replace function doesn't change src.

I think what you want to do is:

```
src = src.replace(/.*([A-Z])\.jpg$/g, "X");
```

Answer (score 1):

src.replace will replace the entire match "http://blah.com/SOMETHING.jpg", not just the part you captured with brackets.

Comment: This is mostly to blame to my wrong testcase, but +1 for correcting me on it anyway :P